# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in nodejs

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I am trying to make a discord level bot and I need to grab some ingo from a json file and compare the length but I get the error in the title at if statement:

```
if(message.author.bot == false && userinput != '!level')
    {   let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./level.json", "utf-8"));
        // console.log(data);
        if(data === undefined)
        {
            console.log("data is undefined");
            return;
            //if date is undefined (failsafe method)
        }
        // for loop looping through array, if we are going to find user, we add +1 experience and exit the loop
        if( data.length > 0){
        for(let i=0;i< data.length; i++)
        if(message.author.id == data[i].userID)
        {
            data[i].exp++;
            fs.writeFileSync("./level.json", JSON.stringify(data));
            i = data.length;
        }
            
        }
        //if file is empty, add user details to file, only run once
        else
        if(data.length <= 0)
        {
        const newuser = {
                    "userID" : message.author.id,
                    "exp" : 1
                }
                data = [newuser];
                fs.writeFileSync("./level.json", JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        
        //is going to add experience to user
        
    }
```

error log:

```
    if( data.length > 0){
             ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at Client.<anonymous>

Comment: To start with `if(data = undefined)` is an `assignment`, not a comparison.  It should be `if(data === undefined)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are *assigning* (single equals) `undefined` to data:

```js
if(data = undefined)
        ^^^
```

If you check with *double equals*, it will work:

```js
if (data == undefined) { ... }
```

You can also do `if (!data) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `if(data = undefined)`. Please note that there is only one `=` sign.

Due to this, the `data` would be assigned as `undefined` and this line would become `if(undefined)`. Hence the if block won't be executed.

Just update this line to `if(data == undefined)`